# How to parse telnet data with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, network-programming

I decided to write a mud client using electron js. Mud is a text based RPG game that uses telnet protocol. Here is my code so far (i just started with nodejs)

```
"use strict";

const net = require('net');
const TelnetInput = require('telnet-stream').TelnetInput;
const TelnetOutput = require('telnet-stream').TelnetOutput;

let socket = net.createConnection(6555, '198.178.123.109', function() {
    let input = new TelnetInput();
    let output = new TelnetOutput();

    //socket.pipe(input).pipe(process.stdout);
    process.stdin.pipe(output).pipe(socket);

    socket.pipe(input).on('data', function(chunk) {
        chunk = chunk.toString() + 'end';

        let split = chunk.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);

        split.forEach(function(line) {
            if (line.match(/end/) == null) {
                line = line + ">--\n\r";
            } else {
                line = line.replace('end', '');
            }

            process.stdout.write(line);
        });
    });

    input.on('will', function(option) {
        if (option == 201) {
            output.writeDo(201);

            var support = new Buffer(1);
            support.write('Core.Supports.Set [ "Room 1", "Char 1", "Comm 1", "Group 1" ]', 0);
            output.writeSub(201, support);
        }
    });

    input.on('sub', function(option, buffer) {
            // console.log(option);
            // console.log(buffer.toString());
    });
});
```

At the moment my problem is, that `socket.pipe(input).on('data'...` does not trigger on each line, but it returns multiple lines. And sometimes the these chunks do not break on new line break.

```
socket.pipe(input).on('data', function(chunk) {
    console.log(chunk.toString());
    console.log("testing\n\r");
});
```

The code above would give the result below. `data` event is triggered 2 times.

```
#############################################################################
##[        --- Welcome to Aardwolf MUD ---        ]##########################
##[                                               ]##########################
##[         Players Currently Online: 3           ]##########################
##[                                               ]##########################
##[     Game Last Rebooted on 06 Jun 18:21:36     ]##########################
#############################################################################
########                                                              #######
########                                                              #######
########                                                              #######
########       _____ _____ ____ _____    ____   ___  ____ _____       #######
########      |_   _| ____/ ___|_   _|  |  _ \ / _ \|  _ \_   _|      #######
########        | | |  _| \___ \ | |    | |_) | | | | |_) || |        #######
########        | | | |___ ___) || |    |  __/| |_| |  _ < | |        #######
########        |_| |_____|____/ |_|    |_|    \___/|_| \_\|_|        #######
########                                                              #######
########                                                              #######
########                                                              #######
##
testing

######                                                              #######
########                                                              #######
#############################################################################
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Enter your character name or type 'NEW' to create a new character
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
What be thy name, adventurer? 
testing
```

So my question is, how could i trigger an event on each/row line? I can split the chunks, but how do i concat different chunks in case the chunk does not end with a line break?

Or perhaps my approach is 100% wrong. These are pretty much my first nodejs lines.

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is wondering. Solution is very simple. I just approached this the wrong way:

```
"use strict";

const net = require('net');

const socket = net.createConnection(6555, '198.178.123.109', ()=> {
    process.stdin.pipe(socket);
});

let line = '';

socket.on('data', chunk => {
    let str = chunk.toString();

    for (let i = 0, len = str.length; i < len; i++) {
        let chr = str[i];
        line += chr;

        process.stdout.write(chr);

        if (/[\n\r]$/.test(chr)) {
            process.stdout.write(line);
            line = '';
        }
    }
});
```